# Displaying a title and description on a jquery slideshow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a preliminary jquery slideshow that I am trying to overlay a title and description on (starting with the title). The slideshow works by changing the margin-left by the width of the images. Right now all of the titles are on top of each other instead of one for each image. I'm planning on implementing next and previous buttons to this as well so instead of clicking the image I'll have next and previous functions.

EDIT: Okay apparently I wasn't clear on my question. All of the titles are stacked on top of each other right now, how do I get the titles to be on the correct images.

PHP/HTML

```
$pic_array = array();
$titles = array();
$descriptions = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pic_array[$count] = $row['pic_url'];
    $titles[$count] = $row['title'];
    $descriptions[$count] = $row['description'];
    $count++;
}
echo "<div id='slider'>
        <ul class='slides'>";
for ($x=0; $x < count($pic_array); $x++) {
    echo " <li class='slide'><img src= " . $dir . $pic_array[$x] . " /></li>";
    echo " <li class='title'>$titles[$x]</li>";
}
echo "   </ul>  
      </div>";
```

CSS

```
#slider {
    width: 450px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#slider .slides {
    display: block;
    width:10000px;
    height: 250px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
#slider .slide {

    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 450px;
    height: 250px;
}
img {
    width: 450px;
    height: 250px;
}
.title {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0px;
    padding: 1rem;
    left:0;
    color:white;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    var width = 450;
    var slide_number = 0;

    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slides = $slider.find('.slides');
    var $slide = $slides.find('.slide');

    $slider.click(function () {
        $slides.animate({'margin-left': '-=' + width}, 0, function () {
            slide_number++;
            if (slide_number == $slide.length ) {
                slide_number = 0;
                $slides.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: That's nice.  So what's your question?

Comment: The titles are on top of eachother when they I need there to be one for each image

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: rather than having `slide` and `title` both be separate `<li>` tags, maybe try combining them into one `<li>` tag and then separate `<div>` tags inside of that. That way you can control their positioning and have one of to of the other but both inside the same container. That way, the container that is moving (the slide) actually has both elements inside of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i cannot made regular comment on your topic so i'll write here.

try not to give .title class position absolute. that whay they all are on top of eachother.

your using overflow hidden so all your component need to be 450 width.

make both title and image `<div>`s into one `<li>`. maybe its solve your width problem.

good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As a couple of the comments indicate, the main problem is that you are using `position: absolute` for your titles.  Once we change that, and then put the titles into the same `<li>` as the images (so that they will move together), that's pretty much it.

You Javascript does not need to change.  The only change that you need to make to your CSS is the `.title` class.  Here's what you'll need for that:

```
.title {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    bottom:55px;
    padding: 1rem;
    left:0;
    color:white;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

And here's the updated PHP/HTML

```
$pic_array = array();
$titles = array();
$descriptions = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pic_array[$count] = $row['pic_url'];
    $titles[$count] = $row['title'];
    $descriptions[$count] = $row['description'];
    $count++;
}
echo "<div id='slider'>
        <ul class='slides'>";
for ($x=0; $x < count($pic_array); $x++) {
    echo " <li class='slide'>
        <div>
            <img src= " . $dir . $pic_array[$x] . " />
        </div>
        <div class='title'>$titles[$x]</div>
    </li>";
}
echo "   </ul>  
      </div>";
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lq85dcz9/